# Inserting datetime values into an informix table fails

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

I am trying to insert a test value `'10.06.2011 10:24'` into an informix **7.3(sadly)** database.
The destination column is

- System.DateTime
- length:16
- precision 10

while these work

```
select  to_date('10.06.2011 10:24', "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") from test;
INSERT into test values('10.06.2011')
```

these aren't

```
insert into test values('10.06.2011 10:24');
insert into test values(to_date('10.06.2011 10:24:00', "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
```

I tried several more thing like adding secounds but none if it worked. All i get as error is a syntax error without any detail on where it is.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manipulate how `DATE` type fields are presented and interpreted with the `DBDATE` environment variable. Setting it to "DMY4." would format the dates as you've shown them.

But as Frank has said, the format of `DATETIME` is fixed: it must be `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fffff'` or part thereof, depending on the scale and precision of the `DATETIME` column in question.

**UPDATE** (the 2nd comment was getting a bit long...)

I'm troubled by your declaration of the format of the 'destination column'. If you run the following:

```
dbschema -d <database> -t <table>
```

... the result will tell you the column definition as Informix understands it. Is it a `DATE` or a `DATETIME` ?

You can insert a `DATETIME` value into a `DATE` column (the time gets truncated), and you can insert a `DATE` into a `DATETIME` column (time defaults to midnight). But the value must be able to be coerced into the target column format, and `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm` is not valid for a `DATETIME`.

Comment: Please see my comment above, i really doubt that the format is 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fffff'

Comment: Errr, no. `DATETIME` columns have *always* been `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ffff`, which is ISO standard for timestamps (or part thereof - datetime precision can be `YEAR TO MONTH`, `DAY TO MINUTE` and so on), going back further than version 7. The interpretation and presentation of `DATE` columns is affected by the setting of the `$DBDATE` environment variable.

Comment: Executing dbschema shows the column really is a date type and not a datetime. The tool i used to display column types before returns 'System.DateTime', which is wrong. There we got the problem. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5):

The format of your date part, `10.06.2011`, you're trying to insert into the `DATETIME` column is wrong.

The accepted format, using your example, is: `2011-10-06 10:24:00`

Comment: As i wrote above, i can insert data using format MM:DD:YYYY. If i use the format you suggest, i get the error "invalid year in date". I think newer versions of the db use the format, but not this. The problem really is how to insert the correct time, the date seems fine.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify: **1)** Is it Informix 7.2, 7.x ? **2)** The description of the `DATETIME` column you're trying to insert into, example: is it `DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE` ? (see [DATETIME datatypes, Section 3-29](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/7881a.pdf)